# Передача методу параметров разных типов данных

Tags: c++

Помогите прояснить следующий вопрос, пожалуйста.

Я хочу создать класс "вектор-в-плоскости" - vector2.

Положим, его параметры:

```
class vector2 {
float vx, vy;
...
};
```

При конструировании, инициализации объектов такого класса:

Конструктору можно не передавать параметров

```
class vector2{
...
vector2(){vx = NAN; vy = NAN};
...
};
void main(){
vector2 Vector;
return 0;
};
```

Можно передать параметры через переменные разных типов, например, int и float, присваивая значение переданных параметров параметрам объекта vx, vy. Подходя к решению этой задачи, я выбираю
единственный известный мне тривиальнейший подход - создаю 4 копии
конструктора:

```
class vector2{
...
vector2(int a, int b){...};
vector2(int a, float b){...};
vector2(float a, int b){...};
vector2(float a, float b){...};
...
};
```

Собственно вопрос, можно ли как-то обойтись одним конструктором, как-то задать его, чтобы он мог принимать разные, или определённые комбинации возможных типов данных входных параметров?
Я пробовал самостоятельно разобраться с вариативным шаблоном, но как-то у меня не получается придумать, как применить его для решения моей задачи, если он вообще позволяет это сделать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vector2(float const a = 0.0f, float const b = 0.0f): vx{a}, vy{b} {}`, `int` передавать не к чему. Если уж очень хочется сделать шаблон с преобразованием параметров, то можно написать так:

```
template
<
    typename x_First = float
,   typename x_Second = float
>
vector2
(
    x_First const & first = x_First{}
,   x_Second const & second = x_Second{}
) noexcept
(
    noexcept(static_cast<float>(first))
    and
    noexcept(static_cast<float>(second))
)
:   vx{static_cast<float>(first)}
,   vy{static_cast<float>(second)}
{
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@VTT, cпасибо за скорый ответ.

Правильно ли я понимаю, что в конкретном приведённом примере, нет смысла делать реализацию для int, если есть для float, т.к. (с некоторыми оговорками) компилятор может самостоятельно провести перевод int  во float, так? Или есть какое-то принципиально другое объяснение? Я раньше не видел такого синтаксиса (начало вашего ответа), не могли бы пояснить как его читать, или как это называется, чтобы можно было загуглить, пожалуйста?

Со вторым блоком кода более менее понятно, используется вариативный шаблон. Единственное, не совсем понятно необходимость использования noexcept и то, почему именно так в него передаются параметры, как это читать/понимать. Раньше не использовал и не сталкивался с noexcept, прочитал спецификацию но с ходу всё же трудно понять что он из себя представляет.

Comment: вопросы к ответам стоит писать в комметариях к самому ответу

Answer (score 0):

Если отвечать чисто на вопрос:

```
template <typename T>
struct identity {
    using type = T;
};

template <typename T>
using identity_t = typename identity<T>::type;

class vector2 {
    float vx, vy;
public:
    template <typename T = float>
    vector2(identity_t<T> _vx, identity_t<T> _vy) 
    : vx{_vx}, vy{_vy} {}
};
```

В данном примере мы используем специальный помощник `identity`, который предотвращает автоматический вывод аргумента шаблона конструктора (В данном случае оно не нужно, так как нам нужен тип `float`). Теперь мы можем принимать любые типы, которые могут неявно преобразовываться к `float` (Кроме `explicit`, конечно же. Для этого нужна более глубока шаблонная магия). Но это только один из возможных подходов (Можно создать чистый шаблонный конструктор, который будет сам преобразовывать типы или специальную функцию, которая будет помогать конструировать объект `vector2`).

В данном случае я показал как можно более *шаблонный* подход. [Вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31942048/when-to-use-the-identity-tmp-trick) основные трюки `identity`.

**PS**: В вашем случае даже `identity` не нужно. Все и так будет приводиться. Пример *ради шаблона*.

Comment: Спасибо за пример, объяснение и доп. материалы. Постараюсь разобраться.